# Group the values according to year

Tags: java, android

For example Question be like of Arraylist

```
array.add("2017",45);
array.add("2015",654);
array.add("2015",19);
array.add("2016",88);
array.add("2016",25);
array.add("2015",45);
```

The output will be

```
array1.get()//45,654,19 
array2.get()//88,25 
array3.get()//45
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: you could use HashMap instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, Arraylist doesn't work in that way.

`void add(int index, Object element)` : This method inserts the specified element E at the specified position in this list.

It shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (will add one to their indices).

Parameters:

index : The index at which the specified element is to be inserted.

element : The element to be inserted.

Exception:
Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified
index is out of range (index  size()).

I suggest HashMap> where year is the key.

**EDIT**

```
public List<Integer> getValueByYear(String year){
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(YourObject object : array){
        if(object.getYear().equals(year){
            values.add(object.getValue())}
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The values are stored in array of object

Comment: Try something like the method in my edit part, should work